# Pentaho Schema Workbench not able to start

Tags: schema, pentaho, workbench

Pentaho Schema Workbench not able to start, it seem the program detect wrong path as screenshot below ";\bin\java".

I try all the way to set in Environment variable but no luck.

[image]

Environment variable all is set JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, PATH

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the _PENTAHO_JAVA entries unless you are directing Pentaho to use a different Java than the systems default.

I would try deleting those two entries, and removing the semicolon from the end of your JAVA_HOME. Then it should pick up the JAVA_HOME properly.

I always have my Java's bin directory in my path too.

Comment: Delete the semicolon behind JAVA_HOME is working, Thanks